# Error in installing my custom keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS “Jammy Jellyfish”.

I have tried to install my team's custom keyboard for the study of bambara (a language in West Africa), a keyboard derived from the French one.

This has worked fine since Ubuntu 14 or even earlier with small adaptations.
The same version had been working OK from Ubuntu 18 to 20.

It doesn't work now ! it's available as usual in Preferences / Keyboard input, but the keys don't give the expected characters... ;(
Any advice welcome while I start my re-engineering...)

**But I need help quickly because I made a mistake** : I replaced two files without taking a backup as I use to do:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

Can someone please send these files from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS “Jammy Jellyfish” ?
Please!

Have a nice evening!

Comment: You can run `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data` to replace whatever you have with the original files.

Comment: This worked OK, thanks a lot, lost files restored - and I can still type this !